# Python: Rotate chart about the center

Tags: python, plot, charts, rotation, jquery-animate

How can I rotate my chart around the center? Is this even possible? Here is my code. Shall I use animate?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import pylab as p
import numpy as np

fig = p.figure()  
ax = Axes3D(fig) 
X = np.arange(-15, 15, 0.3) 
Y = np.arange(-15, 15, 0.3) 
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)  

R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)

Z = np.sin(R)/R

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=2, cstride=2,cmap=cm.jet)

p.show()
```

Here is my output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the plot can be rotated around a specified axis.

```
view_init(elev=None, azim=None)
```

function can be used to rotate the plots.

Please take a look at the documentation in this link: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html